# Problema al ubicar un widget donde está el cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy tratando de hacer que un widget esté siempre donde está el cursor. Sin embargo, el widget está "parpadeando" entre dos zonas:

-La esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla

-La ubicación del cursor, donde quiero que aparezca.

Aquí les dejo un código de ejemplo con el error que me está sucediendo:

```
from tkinter import *

v=Tk()

l=Label(bg="black")
l.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100)

v.bind("<Motion>", lambda Event:l.place(x=Event.x, y=Event.y))
v.mainloop()
```

Mi versión de Python es 3.8.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final hayé la solución a mi problema usando `v.after`, no es la manera más limpia, pero aun así sirve!

```
from tkinter import *

v=Tk()

l=Label(bg="black")
l.place(x=0, y=0, width=100, height=100)

def place():
    curx = v.winfo_pointerx() - v.winfo_rootx()
    cury = v.winfo_pointery() - v.winfo_rooty()

    l.place(x=curx, y=cury)
    v.after(10, place)

place()
v.mainloop()
```